# SwiftUI: ui slots and slot props?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm starting with Swift (coming from front-end) with test projects and have a question about view and view builders

For reference: in a front-end framework Vue.js there is a concept of slots and slot props https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots
Same goes for Svelte https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#slot and also same functionality can be achieved in React

For example I have some generic list that has some basic layout and makes some logic (filtration, sorting etc) inside and I want to use it to pass a list and display list items however I want, and if I won't provide a builder, there will be some default view that is specified inside that list

Is there any way to achieve such functionality in SwiftUI/UIKit?

What I've tried to do is something like the next code, I simplified it to show the general idea

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTestView\<T: Hashable, Content: View\>: View {
    private let items: \[T\]
    private let listItemBuilder: (ListItemBuilderParams) -\> Content

    init(
        _ list: [T],
        @ViewBuilder listItem: @escaping (_ params: ListItemBuilderParams) -> Content
    ) {
        self.items = list
        self.listItemBuilder = listItem
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
                listItemBuilder(.init(item1: item, item2: item, item3: item)) // ?? Text(String(item))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var filteredItems: [T] {
        // ...some filtration
        return items
    }
    
    struct ListItemBuilderParams {
        let item1: T
        let item2: T
        let item3: T
        // ... and possible more
    }
}

struct ViewWithList: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListTestView(\[1, 2, 3, 4\]) { params in
            Text(String(params.item1))
            Button(String(params.item2)) {}
            Text(String(params.item3))
        }
    }
}
```

But it won't compile because in `ViewWithList` I get an error `Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred`

But it compiles if I pass all the params as plain arguments list, without a struct, but it may get really messy because there is no way to omit some specific arguments and I have to list them all in closure

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTestView<T: Hashable, Content: View>: View {
    private let items: [T]
    private let listItemBuilder: (T, T, T) -> Content

    init(
        _ list: [T],
        @ViewBuilder listItem: @escaping (T, T, T) -> Content
    ) {
        self.items = list
        self.listItemBuilder = listItem
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
                listItemBuilder(item, item, item) // ?? Text(String(item))
            }
        }
    }

    private var filteredItems: [T] {
        // ...some filtration
        return items
    }
}

struct ViewWithList: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListTestView([1, 2, 3, 4]) { item1, item2, item3 in
            Text(String(item1))
            Button(String(item2)) {}
            Text(String(item3))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are running up against Swift's strong typing; types need to be determined, and are checked, at compile time, so the approach probably won't work the way it does in JavaScript based environments. You will also have problems with your computed `filteredList` property as changes in computed properties won't trigger a view refresh.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone is interested, I've managed to implement similar thing and it looks like this:)

```
import SwiftUI

typealias ItemBuilder<T: Hashable, TItem> = (ItemBuilderParams<T>) -> TItem

struct VeryAbstractListView<T: Hashable, TItem: View>: View {
    private let items: [T]
    private let itemBuilder: ItemBuilder<T, TItem>

    private var hasItemBuilder = true

    init(
        _ items: [T],
        @ViewBuilder item: @escaping ItemBuilder<T, TItem>
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.itemBuilder = item
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            let item = items[i]

            // if view used without itemBuilder, just render the default view
            if hasItemBuilder {
                itemBuilder(.init(item: item, index: i))
            } else {
                Text("Default view \(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}

// builder params on the top level to help swift infer generic types correctly
struct ItemBuilderParams<T: Hashable> {
    let item: T
    let index: Int
}

extension VeryAbstractListView {
    // itemBuilder is optional
    init(_ items: [T]) where TItem == EmptyView {
        self.init(items) { _ in EmptyView() }
        self.hasItemBuilder = false
    }
}

#Preview {
    Group {
        VeryAbstractListView([1, 2, 3, 4])
        VeryAbstractListView([1, 2, 3, 4]) { params in
            Text("Custom view \(params.item)")
        }
    }
}
```

And you can go even further and enchance the default view itself, but I don't know if there any downsides of such approach in terms of performance

```
import SwiftUI

typealias ItemBuilder<T: Hashable, TItem> = (ItemBuilderParams<T>) -> TItem

struct VeryAbstractListView<T: Hashable, TItem: View>: View {
    private let items: [T]
    private let itemBuilder: ItemBuilder<T, TItem>

    private var hasItemBuilder = true

    init(
        _ items: [T],
        @ViewBuilder item: @escaping ItemBuilder<T, TItem>
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.itemBuilder = item
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                let item = items[i]
                let view = VeryAbstractListItemView(i: i)

                // if view used without itemBuilder, just render the default view
                if hasItemBuilder {
                    itemBuilder(.init(item: item, index: i, view: view))
                } else {
                    view
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// builder params on the top level to help swift infer generic types correctly
struct ItemBuilderParams<T: Hashable> {
    let item: T
    let index: Int
    let view: VeryAbstractListItemView
}

extension VeryAbstractListView {
    // itemBuilder is optional
    init(_ items: [T]) where TItem == EmptyView {
        self.init(items) { _ in EmptyView() }
        self.hasItemBuilder = false
    }
}

struct VeryAbstractListItemView: View {
    let i: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("Default view \(i)")
    }
}

#Preview {
    Group {
        VeryAbstractListView([1, 2, 3, 4])
            .padding()
        VeryAbstractListView([1, 2, 3, 4]) { params in
            Text("Custom view \(params.item)")
        }
        .padding()
        VeryAbstractListView([1, 2, 3, 4]) { params in
            let isEven = params.index.isMultiple(of: 2)

            HStack {
                if isEven {
                    Text("Default view is flipped!")
                }

                params.view
                    .rotationEffect(isEven ? .degrees(180) : .zero)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to follow the "single responsibility" principle, which would make things simpler / easier to implement:

1. List View is responsible for building and displaying the list of views, based on provided items, possibly with filter / sort buttons. It won't have filter logic, or any other functional logic:

```
// Notice that T was changed to Identifiable as recommended for ForEach
struct ListTestView<T: Identifiable, Item: View>: View {
    
    // Items provided and linked to a parent
    @Binding var items: [T]
    
    // Functions can be a constant
    @ViewBuilder let itemView: (T) -> Item
    let filter: () -> Void
    let sort: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Filter", action: filter)
                Button("Sort", action: sort)
            }
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    itemView(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. The item is any Identifiable structure. For example based on your example, it could be:

```
struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // example, could be set to something more consistent in reality
    let field1: String
    let field2: String
    let field3: String
}
```

3. Item View (each concrete implementation of it) is responsible for displaying a single item. It needs no flexibility, as it will receive directly what it needs to display:

```
struct MyItemView: View {
    
    let myItem: MyItem
    
    let buttonAction: (MyItem) -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(myItem.field1)
            Button(myItem.field2, action: callAction)
            Text(myItem.field3)
        }
    }
    
    // Calls buttonAction with the MyItem 
    func callAction() {
        buttonAction(myItem)
    }
}
```

4. And now the Parent View (the one that is responsible for concrete list with concrete items) is the one holding logic about how to sort / filter them, and provide them to view model.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Those can also move to ViewModel
    @State var items: [MyItem]
    @State var clickedText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Clicked \(clickedText)")
            ListTestView(
                items: $items,
                itemView: itemViewBuilder,
                filter: filter,
                sort: sort
            )
        }
    }
    
    func itemViewBuilder(_ item: MyItem) -> some View {
        MyItemView(
            myItem: item,
            buttonAction: performAction
        )
    }
    
    func performAction(_ item: MyItem) {
        clickedText = "\(item.field1), \(item.field3)"
    }
    
    func filter() {
        // For example
        items = [items[0]]
    }
    
    func sort() {
        // For example
        items = items.reversed()
    }
}
```

Further you can implement the reusable procedures for filter, sort and so on, but do so in a separate class, or even an extension of `Array`